# Firestore data modeling to get x unknown amount of documents that the user has permission to access from collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What i want is to be able to send a query that returns all teams that a user is in so f.ex. uid1 would return team1, but not the rest of the teams. My current model doesn't work as i just get permission problems as the user doesn't have permission to read all the documents in the Teams collection.

The Teams collection can contains multiple teams, and users can be a part of multiple teams.

This is how my current firestore is organized:

```
Users:
    uid1
        firstname: xxxx
        lastname: yyyy
Teams:
     team1
         subCollection1
             ...
         subCollection2
             ...
         members
             uid1
             ...
         roles
             uid1
                 role: dev
    team2
        ...
```

I have only been able to think of two solutions, but neither seem very good.

1. Have a list/subcollection under each user in the Users collection that contains all the teams a user is in.
2. Have a field of type array in each document inside the Teams collection that contains all the uid's of the team members. (then use .where("members", "array-contains", uid))

What would be the best way to organize data to allow the functionality i want?

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subcollection under Users and perform a `collectionGroup` query to get all users that are on that team, or a regular query to get all the teams a user is on. You would just store the teamID in the subcollection and maybe some other static information if you want.

```
Users:
    uid1
        firstname: xxxx
        lastname: yyyy
        teams (collection)
             teamID (document)
             teamID (document)
    uid2
        firstname: xxxx
        lastname: yyyy
        teams (collection)
             teamID (document)
Teams:
     team1
         subCollection1
             ...
         subCollection2
             ...
         roles
             uid1
                 role: dev
      team2
          ...
```

Now there is also no need to store `members` under `Teams` since you can run all queries through the `Users` collection, and once you have the `teamID` you can do whatever you want with it.

You would also have to change the permissions for the `collectionGroup` query for this to work.

Such as:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{path=**}/teams/{teamID} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;

    }

    match /users/{userID}/teams/{teamID} {

      allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would i write the security rules such that only members of the team can read who the members of the team are. I tried
`match /{path=**}/teams/{team} {
   allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/teams/$(team));
    }`
but it doesnt seem to work as i get permission denied errors.